# SHA256 IVs / NUMS numbers

Tags: sha-256, backdoors

I've read that if the IVs for SHA256 were arbitrary and / or unknown (secret) than a backdoor to predict outputs would be possible.

How do the values chosen for the IVs / publishing the values prevent such a backdoor and if the values were arbitrary / secret, how would such a backdoor work?

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be more accurate if one says "if IV were *chosen* arbitrary and / or unknown, then backdoors *might* be possible".

From what I know, the SHA256 IVs are chosing from the fraction parts of well known irrational numbers (though I'm not sure it's sqrt(2) or pi or something else). This way, the only being(s) capable of crafting a backdoor, would be the supreme being(s) beyond our Universe.

Similarly, in [RFC 3526](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3526.txt), modulus is chosing using pi to avoid backdoors. As a side note, sadly, small modulus are vulnerable to mass pre-computation attacks.

Comment: FIPS-180-4, section 5.3.3; no need for guessing.

Comment: The term normally used is "Nothing up my sleeve" numbers - that's missing from the answer. I'd say that it is only part of the security, if such numbers are used some attacks *may* be avoided, but the algorithm can still be intentionally weak. It would even be possible to choose a "nothing up my sleeve" number that is chosen so that an attack is possible; it's just that pre-computation of a specific number is made impossible due to the size of the number.